# How to delete duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, subquery

The query:

```
DELETE FROM orders WHERE sales_id IN (
    SELECT sales_id FROM orders GROUP BY sales_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

There is an error:
 `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM clause`.

How to resolve this? Please help.

Comment: qualify your column names.

Comment: @ergonaut: irrelevant. there's only one table involved, and the error tells you exactly what the problem is: you can't modify a table that you're selecting from in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
This behaviour is documented at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

You will need to stop using the nested subquery and execute the operation in two parts, or alternatively use a simple where clause.

If you want to use subquery than you can try giving alias name to the table in subquery like this:

```
DELETE FROM orders WHERE sales_id IN (
    SELECT sales_id FROM (
        SELECT * FROM orders
    ) AS t1 GROUP BY sales_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: Error 1241 : Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Comment: for me it is working fine , you can also try replacing * by column name